# What exactly is a purely HTML5 application?

Tags: javascript, html, native, hybrid

We often hear 3 kinds of apps :
1. Purely HTML5
2. Hybrid apps
3. Native apps

So what are the key differences between these items and what exactly is a purely HTML5 app?

Thanks
Smitha

Comment: A pure HTML5 app runs in the browser with no other dependencies.

Comment: you can google it  http://www.50pixels.com/blog/native-web-or-hybrid-apps/

Comment: Thanks for the valuable updates. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking of e.g. iPhone and Android,

- native apps are built in ObjC/Java.
- HTML5 apps are built in JS/HTML/CSS and displayed using the native browser.
- hybrid apps are built from both, with a custom-built wrapper (in ObjC/Java) that interacts with HTML/JS/CSS code (often with the help of a library such as PhoneGap).

Native apps are non-portable but fast; HTML5 apps are portable but limited to what HTML5 allows you (for example, you can't access a SD card from JS). Hybrid approach gives you portability of a HTML app, while you can still write extensions in native code to handle system-dependent, or time-critical sections.

Comment: "using the native browser" - not necessarily the "native" one, HTML5 apps usually respect Open Web Standards and can execute in any modern browser that the OS supports.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Yeah, I might have written it clearer; I meant you're not writing any native code yourself, you delegate it to any browser (which would itself be written in native code), whether Mobile Safari, or Opera Mini, or whatever else you download.